# Business Intelligence Development Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, bids

I can't find Business Intelligence Development Studio in Sql Server 2005.
I have installed Visual Studio 2008 and Sql Server 2005 Standard edition.
How can i view

Answer (score 1):

You can tell if it is installed by looking at "new project" in Visual Studio. Do you have BI projects available?

- If so, this is it. You can now develop BI stuff.
- If not, did you check the box under client tools when installing? Run install again.

BIDS isn't a separate install but a Visual Studio plug-in

Answer (score 0):

You do need to select it when installing though. You could probably run a reinstall and add it if you don't have it already.

Answer (score 0):

while installing, you might have not selected the feature. in this case, re run the Installation process.

Comment: Please do not spam the link to your blog. Also, please don't outsource information onto your blog, keep information on this site whenever possible.

Comment: I am sorry it was 5 months back and I was new to the forum at that time. Since i know the etiquette's now - I'll not do that. Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 0):

You Must Install SSDT(Sql Server Data Tools) Tools 
When you Installed that , and you want Create New Project, you must see Business Intelligence Section in part of Template